# REST insert new task item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest

I successfully inserting item in task list, but with only title, like this:

```
string message = "'Title': 'NewTitle2 updated'"
string json = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.MyTasksListItem' }," + message + "}";
```

In message string I want to add `Assigned to` and `Date` along with `Title`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I've used this code to create a task setting both the AssignedTo and DueDate field values.

```
function addItem(userId) {
    var due = new Date();
    due.setDate(due.getDate() + 7);

    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Tasks')/Items",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.TasksListItem" },
            Title: "Sample Task",
            AssignedToId: userId,
            DueDate: due
        }),
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    });
    call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var div = jQuery("#message");
        div.text("Item added");
    });
    call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thnks for your response.

Comment: I am sending http request through c# code and HttpRequestMessage used to create message and then send it to server. I have also tried the way string message = "'Title': 'NewTitle2 updated', 'AssignedToId': 11" but this is not working

Answer (score 0):

I've created task from workflow directly writing on list.
To set the `Assigned to` property try to set `AssignedToId` with the id of a user(is it a current user o you need to find it by a name?).

Comment: very very thnks but this is not current user, he can be anyone from sharepoint users

Comment: 'AssignedToId':'10' is also giving error

Comment: "message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected."}

Comment: <d:AssignedToId xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
        <d:element m:type="Edm.Int32">11</d:element>
      </d:AssignedToId>

Comment: Have you tried with int? `string message = "'Title': 'NewTitle2 updated', 'AssignedToId': 11"` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that also, I am very much confused no help from Google, a full day on searching this to complete my task.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: JSON.stringify({
        "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.TasksListItem" },
        Title: "Sample Task",
        AssignedToId: {results: [userId] },
        DueDate: due
    }),
```