# Assigning Task to Group using REST and SharePoint JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, workflow-tasks-list

I found myself in an unfortunate position of being unable to use SharePoint Designer to build workflows and thus am having to rebuild an approval workflow in JavaScript. I am using [REST to insert a new task item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/77502/79822) but need to expand it to assign the task to all users in a group and make it so that whoever in the group is the first to approve or reject the task will set the task status.

Do I simply need to replace the userId in `AssignedToId: userId` with `groupId`? Or would I use the REST API to GET a list of users (and their IDs) from the group name using `url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('" + strSPGroupName + "')/users"` and then create an array of the user ids for use in this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem" },
    Title: "Sample Task",
    AssignedToId: { 'results': [11,22] },
    DueDate: due,
    Status: "In Progress"
})
```

I have my Task list AssignedTo column set to `Allow Multiple Selections: Yes` and `Allow Selection Of: People and Groups`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "__metadata" property from the "AssignedToId" object:
Try this out:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem" },
    Title: "Sample Task",
    AssignedToId: { "__metadata": { "type": "Collection(Edm.Int32)"},'results': [11,22] },
    DueDate: due,
    Status: "In Progress"
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the ```_metadata``` property. Any thoughts on how it would look if I wanted to assign a task to a group, rather than an individual?

Comment: It is the same method, replace the UserIds with GroupIds, the ids of groups and people are unique.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!